# How to open downloaded files in Chrome / Opera 15+ in default application automatically?

Tags: opera-next

In Firefox, we can set the following options to deal with downloaded files in Options->Application tab:

1. Ask what to do
2. Save
3. Preview in Firefox
4. save and use default app
5. save and use a chosen app

In opera (mine is 19.0.1326.63), for example in case of a pdf file, we can preview it in browser by an add-on that uses HTML5, but if the add-on is disabled, only way to open it is to save and manually open it.

I guess, it is same in case of Google Chrome too, as these two browsers share similar behavior.

Is there any way to save and automatically open the file, as can be done in Firefox?

Comment: What is your Operating System?

Comment: @JulianMoreno windows 8.1, x64

Comment: There is an [Open with Application extension](https://addons.opera.com/en-gb/extensions/details/open-with-application/?display=en#feedback-container) for Opera. I did not test it since I came here for having ics files opened automatically in my calender as this works in Firefox. I will stick to Firefox as long as this is not solved. Anyone knows how to use this extension with ics files?

Answer (score 0):

Within Chrome you can simply select to "Always open files of this type" which automatically opens the files after they're downloaded.

[image]

Comment: In chrome when I download a file type and it asks me to open I click "Always open files of this type" and from there on it opens by itself...